# Java Return int into buffer.getInt

Tags: java, buffer

I am using buffer with Comparator of PriorityQueue (to compare elements of streams) by reading next value with buffer.getInt(). Unfortunately, when I am  comparing it next time, I am loosing this value.
So, is it possible to return int back to buffer in java?
I tried smth like putInt but it is different..
Thanks in advance.

I am working on implementation of External Merger Sort

```
package sort;
import java.util.Comparator;
import inputStream.Mapping.*;

public class extComparator implements Comparator<MapInp>{

    @Override
    public int compare(MapInp o1, MapInp o2) {
        Integer a = o1.readNext();
        Integer b = o2.readNext();
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Then, I am using it in another file:

```
heap = new PriorityQueue<MapInp>(numOfFilesNM/d, new extComparator());
heap.add(new MapInp("data/inp.data"));
....
int t = heap.peek().readNext(); //so, here I am comparing values and loosing the value
```

MapInt readNext:

```
public int readNext() {
    if(fileLen-pos-lastPos>bufSize) bufCap = bufSize;
    else bufCap = (int) (fileLen-pos-lastPos);
    if(buffer.position()==buffer.capacity()) {
        lastPos+=pos;
        buffer.clear();
    try {
        buffer = inpCh.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, lastPos,bufCap);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pos=0;
    }
    pos+=4;
    return buffer.getInt();
}
```

unfortunately, I still have not resolved it. Sorry, but may be sharing of whole code will be better: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zqceyg8j6u9kvg7/test.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please show the code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ThomasEdwin added. The main problem - is how make comparison of two values in the stream. Now I can do it and loose values. I hope that it is possible to turn back the value into the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not show the definition of `MapInp`, but obviously it has a method called `readNext`. The name of that method suggests that it advances some sort of iterator. Iterators move forward.

`heap.peek()` returns the top item from the `PriorityQueue<MapInp>` without disturbing the queue. Probably you need to call some other method other than `MapInp.readNext()` in order to obtain the value of `t`.

BTW, your comment `so, here I am comparing values and loosing the value` seems incorrect, because I would be surprised if `readNext` functions according to the comment.

Comment: MapInp is a custom class for mapping. There is no other functions. Probably, I need to change smth in this class..

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, is it possible to return value to MappedByteBuffer ?

Comment: MappedByteBuffer can be read from and written to. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html

Answer (score 0):

You are violating *every* rule of a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-), but let's cut it down to size.

A `Comparator` must have **no side-effects**.

You have no control whatsoever over how and when the `compare()` method is called, so having the method read a "next" value from somewhere is entirely wrong!!!

The ordering of a [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is established as elements are added. You are not allowed to change the value of an element, in a way that affects the sort order, while it is part of the queue.

You're doing it entirely wrong. If you have N streams of values, that are each individually ordered (as you'd need for a merge sort), then read the first value from each stream and add to queue. Then `poll​()` the head value, get the next value from the stream that provided that value, and put it in the queue.

I will leave the actual coding of that to you, but your first step is to throw away what you're currently doing, as far as you can manage to throw it. It is really that far from what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am storing these preordered streams in queues and then merging it to one file (according to the external merge algorithm). The problem is loosing of values when I am filling this file - I found that it happens because of this comparison (so, I am reading the next value of two streams and changing its position).

I've tried to use poll() but it kills even more values and I am receiving like all the nulls in the result.

Comment: @Luno What would be the point of that? You have to throw away your code. It's bad. The `Comparator` must not modify the objects being compared, and calling `next()` is a modification. *Re-think* what you're doing.